# Entity Framework with PostgreSQL not saving data

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

I have a connection to PostgreSQL using Entity Framework.

When retrieving data, everything works okay, also migrations are working well, the problem is during insertion of the data.

I assume its due to the ID not being automatically generated, but since I'm new to Entity Framework, I do not know how to move forward.

Here is my `AddUser` function:

```
public Task<EntityEntry<UserModel>> AddUser(UserModel user) => this.context.Users.AddAsync(user);
```

This is the corresponding model class:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace WishareIntegrationApi.Entities
{
    public class UserModel
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string token { get; set; }
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        public string photoURL { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public DateTime registeredAt { get; set; }
        public string birthday { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I add data into table manually and fill in the ID it will insert the data, if the ID is not part of the insert query, it will fail even tho it should be auto_increment.

The database is generated from the code using migrations.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you just forgot to call `SaveChanges`?

Comment: @Evk You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Evk stated, I was missing call of the SaveChanges function.